# Clang AST parsing and unique_ptr on windows - libc++

Tags: c++, clang

I'm currently using clang under windows, but only to generate an AST from my headers as a code generation tool.
Now I'm facing a problem with unique_ptr not being parsed which should be solved by telling clang to use either libc++ or libstdc++ in the command line arguments. But I am on windows.

I know libc++ hasn't completely been ported to windows yet, so I'm now considering listdc++.

But the thing is : I'm only parsing headers to an AST, I really only need clang to get the correct header to correctly parse the references to std::unique_ptr in my file. It shouldn't be much more than downloading the source and telling clang where to find the right headers, right ? But I don't know how to do that, clang is quite obscure.

Do you think that is possible to achieve and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found, quite simply, I just need to pass the include directory manually when calling the parser.

```
index.parse(file, [ '-x', 
                    'c++', 
                    '-std=c++11',
                    '-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src' ])
```

There is probably a way to setup my environment more cleanly, but for my use it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MinGW or Visual Studio- Clang can handle both stdlib implementations on Windows if you set the language options appropriately.

Comment: Do you have any pointers as to how I would do that ? I'm trying to avoid building clang on this machine and thought since I'm only parsing syntax and not compiling anything it should be possible without.